# hide the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one save button and drop down it will generate dynamically. when user select the drop down one value save button was disable how?
Already i try with css(display:none),jquery(attr) option not working so please any another method is there??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "select[id^='dropdown_status']", function() {
    var status_value = $(this).val();
    if (status_value == '2' || status_value == '3') {
      //button disable code
      //css code not working
      $(.submit).css('display', 'none');
      $('.submit').hide();
      //jquery code not working 
      //$(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
      //$(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status" id="dropdown_status414938923" size="1" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Grapees</option>
    <option value="3">mango</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="update" value="Save">
```

Comment: do u mean on select drop down option hide save button ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: you need quotes around `.submit` here: `$(.submit).css('display','none');`

Comment: 1) remove select in display:none 2) $(.submit).css('display','none');    3) replace $('.submit').css('display','none');

Comment: that's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {

  if (this.value == '2' || this.value == '3')
    $("input").prop('disabled', true);
  else
    $("input").prop('disabled', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status" id="dropdown_status414938923" size="1" tabindex="-1" title="">
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Grapees</option>
<option value="3">mango</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="update" value="Save">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `prop disabled` for disable and `addClass` to hide.

```js
// If only want to disable
$('.submit').prop('disabled',true);
//if want to hide
$('.submit1').addClass('hide');
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="update" value="Save">
<input type="submit" class="submit1" name="update" value="Save">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdownstatus').on('change', function() {
          var status_value = ( this.value );
           if (status_value == '2' || status_value=='3')
          {
           $('.submit').css('display','none');
          }
          else{
           $('.submit').css('display','block');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="status" class="dropdownstatus" id="dropdown_status414938923" size="1" tabindex="-1"title="">
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Grapees</option>
      <option value="3">mango</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="update" value="Save">
  </body>
</html>
```